# Why requests.post() does not use a provided proxy in python?

Tags: python, http, proxy

I am trying to send a post request with a list of http proxies. For a moment I though that the proxies where working fine, until I add a fake proxy to the list to make sure that everything is working like this:

```py
def func_name(i):
  url = 'https://www.some-url.com/Cart/ajax/page.php'

  # Proxies to connect with
  proxies_list = [
    'http://1.1.1.1:2000',
    'http://2.2.2.2:2000',
    'http://1.2.3.0:2000'       # This is the fake one
  ]
  proxy_index = random.randint(0, len(proxies_list) - 1)
  proxy = {"http": proxies_list[proxy_index]}

  # List of user agents
  headers_list = [
    'Linux Mozilla 5/0',
    'Linux Mozilla 5/0',
    'Linux Mozilla 5/0'
  ]
  headers_index = random.randint(0, len(headers_list) - 1)
  headers = {'user-agent':headers_list[headers_index], 'Accept-Encoding':'none'}

  payload = {'dataToValidate':str(i),'actionName':'nc_signup'}
  answer = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, proxies=proxy, data=payload).json()
  print(answer)
```

When `proxy_index = random.randint(0, len(proxies_list) - 1)` picks the fake one I get an answer anyways, the reason for that may be because the `requests.post()` function doesn't even use the argument `proxies=proxy` as expected.

Comment: I don't think you're [using the `proxies` kwarg correctly](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies)

Answer (score 1):

Since you only construct the `proxy` object with an `http` option, the HTTPS URL you're trying to load is not proxied. Changing

```
proxy = {"http": proxies_list[proxy_index]}
```

to

```
proxy = {"http": proxies_list[proxy_index], "https": proxies_list[proxy_index]}
```

should fix the problem.